# <p:slider> causes JS error "TypeError: h is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, slider

I have a `<p:inputText>` containing a price value with two fraction digits (e.g. `1,23` in Germany or `1.23` in US). The formatting of the number can easily be done using the `<f:convertNumber>`.

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.price}">
    <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="#{false}" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" />
</p:inputText>
```

But this does not work together with the `<p:slider>` component. Same thing without fractions but with grouped values like 20.000.000. Does anyone know how to get this running?

```
<p:inputText id="txt1" value="#{quoteFinance.kms}">
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="0" />
</p:inputText>  
<p:slider for="txt1" />
```

When sliding the slider, I get a javascript error: `TypeError: h is undefined`

I've asked the same question on PrimeFaces forum, but no answer.
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14401&p=107517#p107517

Answer (score 3):

> *TypeError: h is undefined*

Those kind of JS/jQuery errors are typically caused by having duplicate different versioned `jquery.js` files loaded by the webapp. PrimeFaces as being a jQuery-based JSF component library already automatically loads a `jquery.js` file by itself. This problem suggests that you're for some reason manually loading another `jquery.js` file yourself via `<script>`/`<h:outputScript>`. If you remove it, then this error should disappear.

You do not need to supply your own copy of `jquery.js`. If you however happen to have a page wherein you'd like to use some jQuery, but the page itself doesn't contain any PrimeFaces component and thus doesn't necessarily auto-include the PrimeFaces-bundled `jquery.js`, then you can always explicitly include it yourself straight from PrimeFaces library by simply adding the following line:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
```

Note: the `target="head"` can be omitted when it's already inside the `<h:head>`. Otherwise, e.g. when inside `<h:body>` or `<ui:define>` of a template client, it will be automatically relocated to head. Another note: you can safely use this line in a page which actually auto-includes PrimeFaces-bundled `jquery.js`. This line won't cause a duplicate inclusion of `jquery.js`. So you can safely put this line in some master template.